# When a question does not have a hardware recommendation, should the answers be removed or the question itself?

Tags: discussion, support, meta

So I recently answered [this question.](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6156/router-that-would-connect-to-2-isps-and-mobile-hotspot-to-provide-quality-servic/6168#6168)

[Answer](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/6168/4504)

ArtofCode deleted my answer, saying that  I didn't recommend a specific piece of hardware. I'm okay with this, he's correct I didn't. My only gripe about the delete process is there doesn't seem to be a way to comment on a deleted answer... but that's not why I'm here.

If there is a case, like others have pointed out... that does not have a fitting hardware rec, **should the mods delete the answers provided or nuke the question?**

I'm sure this has been addressed in the past, I would like to open up the discussion about this specific question. **Delete the answers or Nuke the question?**

I feel like in my case, I could have revised my answer to give some information on hardware specifics... but it would have irrelevant because the bonding device is provided by the ISP.

Comment: There's a difference between bonding and load-balancing.  The question is a bit confused: it describes load-balancing, but asks for bonding-like results.

Comment: Why do you think it's asking for load balancing? Serious question.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I agree that it'd be nice to let users comment on their own deleted answers.

On the topic of 'impossible' requests, see [What should we do with questions asking for hardware that doesn't exist?](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/311/1) In the end, we can't expect moderators to be subject matter experts in everything. I don't have any issues with an answer (as Gilles laid out) that says "this *can't* exist because x, y, and z," or even "no one currently sells this".

You're welcome to edit your answer and flag for it to be undeleted.

Comment: I understand that, so in my case. My original answer should have been sufficient.. because the user was asking for hardware that's simply not available at the consumer level. I explained why, how to obtain what they are looking for. So, with that being said. How can we make this the policy? That if there is no hardware the meets the requirements, a detailed explanation will suffice as an answer. It's not my call either way, it just seems an area where a decision needs to be made from the elders.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from the mess of meta posts we have, the current stance is that if a question doesn't have any hardware that answers it, then it's okay to post an answer saying that -

> There is currently no hardware that is an exact match to your specifications. However, [this product] is similar, and might do what you're looking for with a little bit of work.

In this case, the requested hardware *does* exist (which is why I deleted your answer).

(And, side note, yes - currently, only moderators can comment on deleted posts, but owners should be able to as well, ideally)

Comment: Doesn't look like we can comment, but I can edit it. I'll throw on some examples of bonding hardware and resubmit for review.